# Novel about transhuman punished by removing augmentations

Tags: story-identification, novel, transhuman

A novel about a human (male I think) who lives in a society where everyone has augmentations allowing immediate access to communication/information (e.g. brain to computer interface, VR, AR) essential for participation in society. He is falsely accused of something that results in his losing his augmentations making it difficult for him to live in said society. He looks to prove his innocence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Donald Kingsbury, [*Psychohistorical Crisis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychohistorical_Crisis) (2001)

An answer to another question contains a detailed description of Donald Kingsbury's take on Isaac Asimov's *Foundation* universe, and in particular the society of the planet Trantor.  The notion of a person being stripped of his augmented memory device is an important premise of this novel:

> Excerpt from answer to [A sci-fi novel about augmented mental power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/176134/78630):
>
> As the novel starts, he has just been found guilty of some terrible offence (he can't remember what!), and his "fam" (an implanted computer which greatly augments the processing power of the normal human brain) has already been taken away from him, and it is destroyed by being fed into a "disintegrator" which causes the fam to vanish in a burst of light. In Kingsbury's vision of the distant future (although this part was his own addition, and had not been true in Asimov's Foundation stories), there will be a time when every citizen desperately needs to have a "fam" hooked up to his brain in order to let him cope with the flood of data which is always around him.

Have a look at the full answer on that page; the other details it lists may fit with your recollection.

Comment: @GaryNunes — I'm glad I was able to help. I've suggested that the forum mark this as a duplicate, but that's not a criticism, it's just for keeping the forum organized. Please don't delete your question; duplicates are *good* because they make it more likely that people will find the answers they're looking for.